# extract tweet content from JSON format using R

Tags: json, r, hadoop, tweets

I have been working on R with JSON files streamed to hadoop database using flume.
Now my question is how can i actually get just the content of the tweets from the JSON files.

The JSON files reside in  "/user/flume/tweets/2013/07/14/06". Specifically, in this folder there are 10 files.

I tried doing:

`tweets=from.dfs("/user/flume/tweets/2013/07/14/06")`.

then on execution of `lenght(tweets)` is shows me only 2.

Is this the right way of doing it?
Please help me out.

My final goal is to make a sentiment analysis on the tweets as they are being streamed to HDFS.